# Macbook All ram being used with no apps open

Tags: mac, memory, virus, anti-virus

I recently was teaching this kid to program, and he wanted to teach me some things in screen flow, so he showed me where to get it, and I got part way through the installer, and then I quit it because it looked really fake. And ever since then, the ram on my Mac has been getting drained extremely fast and I can't barely use it. I'm assuming this is a virus, but I can't be sure. I downloaded the avast! app and I couldn't even finish the installation before my computer said I had no ram left. All I had was the installer open, and I have 8GB of ram installed. I had to shut it down, and I restarted it and got it installed, but after like 3 minutes of scanning, it just gets really slow and now I can't ever stop the scan, and it's not scaning anymore files. I had to ask this question on my phone because my computer is too slow. I also replaced my old 4GB ram with 8GB that I got from crucial about 2 weeks ago, so it's possible it could be defective, but it worked fine until now. I'd really appreciate any help or advice on what to do.

## Edit

I am on a Mid 2010 13in MacBook Pro, with OS X 10.8 installed and 8GB of ram that I bought, if that matters

Comment: Your description of the problem is very vague and confusing. For example, you say things like "my computer said i had no ram left". What exactly does that mean? Did you get an error message? What was the exact text of the message?

Comment: I got a message saying there is no ram avalible for applications

Answer (score 0):

Try following the steps here to reinstall your OS:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

This should keep your data in place, but ultimately you may need to backup what you can and do a complete erase and install of the system.